# HTML5/Js client-side DB

Tags: javascript, database, html

We're starting development of a client application. No servers, just HTML5/JS. How to organize a local, non-relational, read-only, one-table DB?

```
Message        | Img       | Code
----------------------------------
File not found | error.png | 15
Access denied  | error.png | 42
```

We want to query row(s) by a field, say, 'Code = 15'. All files should be local.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need cross browser support then I would recommend [localStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).

There is a nice abstraction. [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) that allows you to store keyvalue pairs in the local storage.

Alternatively if you want proper SQL you can use [Web SQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) but wikipedia [claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database) it's only supported by Opera/Safari/Chrome.

Example of store:

```
var Row = {
  Message:"File Not Found",
  Img: "error.png",
  Code: 15
}

store.set(Row.Code, Row);
...
store.get("15");
```

It does rely on JSON which is supported by modern browsers and IE8+. To support older browsers use [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: 1. How to load a table to the storage the first time? 2. The table has multiple columns, using pairs requires more than a single query.

Comment: No, I don't need SQL. Getting a dataset object(s) with a condition ('field =value') is enough.

Comment: @noober updated with an example. localStorage is a document storage so it's noSQL. You store JSON data by (unique) key.

Comment: If I have the table in JS initially, I'd better write a function with operator 'for'. I want to keep the data separately, say, in XML. Since it looks impossible to read local XML file, the best solution is design-time [XML]->[JS array] converter.

Comment: @noober or keep the the data in JSON rather then XML. Then include it as `<script>`